# What does User $user do in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to figure some code out but I'm not exactly sure what this does:

```
User $user
```

Does it create an instance of the User class? Is it the same as $user = new User();

```
public function settings(User $user){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('settings', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: In what context?

Comment: I've added the function I'm looking at. The function  I'm looking at takes a User $user parameter and I'm not sure how it is used. I'm also not sure why is user compacted instead of just sending $user.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part will refer to a `use` statement at the top your file, which will point to a class (in this case your `User` model I assume). It's basically saying that the variable that is passed to the function will be called `$user`, and that it must be an instance of the `User` class. If you try to send anything other than an instance of a `User` class then the code will throw an error for you.

**Edit**

It very unnecessary to send the User object through to this function and then reassign it from the Auth facade. Take one approach or the other, not both.